# Submitting app started by other developer

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I am trying to submit an app started by another dev, he created all the certificates and provisioning profiles, and I can't have that generated developer's profile by him because he is unreachable. I do have access to the apple developer account which was used to submit the app in the first place. What should I do? Revoke and create new certificates or which are my options?

Comment: checkout given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can revoke this certificate or you can create another distribution certificate, it's on you, but I suggest to revoke that certificate because you never going to use it

Perform following steps

1. Revoke previous distribution certificate.
2. Generate new distribution certificate by using **codesigningcertificate**, generated from your mac.
3. Download generated distribution certificate and install it.
4. Assign newly created distribution certificate to provisioning profile of app.
5. Download the provisioning profile and install it.

After all these steps, you are set to upload your app

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do this but for that also you need that develoepr and distribution certificate.

So its better if you have account credentials generate new one as per on your bundlename and use it.

Answer (score 0):

- There is no need to revoke the certificates. You can login to
  developer account and download the old certificates and provisioning
  profiles of your app. Make sure you are downloading distribution
  certificate for submitting to app store. Once you download the
  certificates just double click on them or drag and drop on your xcode
  icon.Same goes for provisioning profile. Then in xcode go to your
  project click on build setting and search for code signing and make
  sure you have selected your distribution certificate for
  debug,distribution,release.Now you can submit your app to appstore.
- If you are not able to find the certificates then you need create
  them using your app id and download them and do the same process as
  described.

Comment: Nut the poster would need the private key used to generate the orignal certificate in order to perform builds.  Based on his questions and lack of access to the original developer, I believe they do not have the key.  In which case, downloading the cert and profiles from the site will do them no good.    I suggest generating a new cert from their Mac so they have the key, cert, and profiles all tied correctly together for their submit to the store.